# How to run a React app as a Gmail Addon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm trying to build a Gmail Addon using React. The problem is, we have to write Gmail Addons using google Apps Script. The reason I chose React is I already built a plugin for outlook using React. If I can use the same for Gmail then I can port the same plugin with minimal effort.

Comment: As you indicate, you cannot.

Answer (score 3):

In short , we can't do that.

Gmail add-on UI is rendered from a google server. The code that we write rests on a server (unless you use clasp for local setup) and runs to render the UI. Also Gmail add-ons do not have access to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use react in gmail addon, as gmail addon script runs on google cloud engine and the resulting html that is generated by the cardservice is returned to the client. For everyaction in the add on, it will go to google app script engine and run the script and return the result.